# Getting Values From Quaternions

Tags: quaternions

I'm using the Quaternion package:

```
<< Quaternions`
```

Very simply, I would like to be able to get the individual components of the quaternions by themselves.

My problem is, if I try

```
Re[FromQuaternion[Quaternion[1,2,3,4]]]
```

I get

```
1+Re[3J+4K]
```

I would like to isolate the components instead.  Then I could get

```
1
```

... or 2 or 3 or 4.  How can I do this?

**ALSO**

Is it possible to convert quaternions into a vector?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See if this helps...

```
q = Quaternion[21, 22, 23, 24];
q[[2]]
FromQuaternion[q] // FullForm
```

> Quaternion[21,22,23,24]
>   22
>   Plus[Complex[21,22],Times[23,J],Times[24,K]]

Now this...

```
q[[1]]
FromQuaternion[q][[1]]
Re[FromQuaternion[q][[1]]]
Im[FromQuaternion[q][[1]]]
List @@ q
```

> 21
>   21+22 I
>   21
>   22
>   {21,22,23,24}

Answer (score 1):

```
   p = FromQuaternion[Quaternion[1, 2, 3, 4]]

 p/.List[Complex[a_,b_],Times[c_,J],Times[d_,K]]->{a,b,c,d}
```

> {1,2,3,4}

To convert it to a vector remove `a` from list.
And since the pattern always stays same, rather give it a name, like

```
  quaternion = List[Complex[a_,b_],Times[c_,J],Times[d_,K]]
```

and call it as `p/.quaternion->{a,b,c,d}`

This approach is helpful when you don't know the parameters with which the `Quaternion` was created